# Advice on Weatherproof HD Camera for Streaming Video / Audio

Tags: camcorder

I am looking to invest in a weatherproof outdoor camera with audio, if possible, to **LIVE** (or at least within the past hour) stream some wildlife. I am looking for advice on what type of camera would be a good buy for rugged use. Night vision would be a great addition.

**Edit: more info...**

This will be a permanent install, or at least 6 to 8 months out of the year. 100 degrees F to -20 degrees F temp swings throughout the year. Will be exposed to wind and snow, but not too much rain. Power will come from hardwire or solar. The camera will be wired to the power and computer about 100' away. I'd also like a 120 degree view or so... something that could show a lot within 5 to 8 feet of something.

EDIT::: I got a $30 cam off Amazon and am running it though a 100' cable with power. It runs into my computer with a KWorld usb connector. It is ok... I haven't found a great source for the streaming yet... iSpy was ok, but wasn't always working. I have it up on UStream now, but quality is not up to the 720 setting. http://www.ustream.tv/channel/chicken-run-cam

I'll keep at it.

Comment: There isn't enough information included with the post.  Are you looking for something that you can permanently deploy outside and stream back to you or something that you can bring with you outside and use for streaming to other people?  This is important as many weatherproofing options don't include an ability to plug in power.

Comment: @AJHenderson Updated the post. Anything else to add there?

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking for something similar but haven't found the perfect solution yet.  If you can live without it streaming in real time, I've heard good things about the Bushnell Trophy Cam series.

http://bushnell.com/all-products/trail-cameras/trophy-cam

Comment: thanks for the comment. I'd like to do live, or close to live, streaming... those are nice trail cams though!

Comment: WOW! I just had an idea that might work with that though... they make the WiFi SD Cards?! http://www.transcend-info.com/products/Catlist.asp?FldNo=24

Comment: ...hmmm... however, you'd run out of space sooner than later... cool idea for an overnight thing :)